# Discord Create Role 404 Not Found error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

When I try:

```
await client.create_role(message.server, name='testrole', color=discord.Colour("FF0000"))
```

I get this error:

```
discord.errors.NotFound: NOT FOUND (status code: 404): Unknown Message
```

Does anyone know how I can get more information about this error?

Answer (score 3):

Do not put the color as a string and add a `0x` in front. So change

```
await client.create_role(message.server, name='testrole', color=discord.Colour("FF0000"))
```

Into

```
await client.create_role(message.server, name='testrole', color=discord.Colour(0xFF0000))
```